# Issues with Maven & GitLab CI

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm having an issue with building a project of mine. We have a self-hosted GitLab and maven repo, however, I'm running into issues when trying to pull dependencies from it. I keep on getting the error; `Not authorized, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.`

I can push artifacts fine, it's just pulling.

I have double-checked that the passwords & usernames are correct, the server and repo ID's match.

EDIT:
Here are my files;

[GitLab CI Output](https://hastebin.com/uniqeriyed.cs)

[ci_settings.xml](https://hastebin.com/laxegovade.xml)

[pom.xml](https://hastebin.com/oticorihun.xml)

[.gitlab.ci](https://hastebin.com/iwicihewej.http)

Comment: No logs, no real error output not configuration information etc. What do you think we should do? Except saying: `Not authorized, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized` look on the error message. Without supplemental information it's impossible to help or even make an educated guess...

Comment: My apologies, I've added the files needed to help.

Comment: You are trying to separate steps `mvn .. compile` from the part `mvn ... deploy` that's a bad thing cause that would result in executing parts several times which costs time. The problem is simply that your `build` in gitlab-ci does not contain a configuration for your settings.xml. Furthermore I strongly recommend to upgrade to most recent version of Maven which supports things like `-ntp,--no-transfer-progress` and contains a lot of fixes etc. Furthermore you should configure the repos to consume artifacts in your settings.xml and not in your pom file.